# How to get the Sender(client process), when running a pydbus service

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, dbus

i am writing a pydbus service, i have registered an interface and provide a method like

```py
import pydbus
from pydbus import SessionBus
from gi.repository import GLib

class Server():
    """
    <node>
      <interface name="org.freedesktop.testSrv">
        <method name="test">
          <arg direction="in" type="s" name="testarg"/>
         </method>
      </interface>
    </node>
   """
   def test(testarg):
       # here i want to access the sender id
       print(testarg)


bus = SessionBus()
bus.publish("org.freedesktop.testSrv", Server())
loop = GLib.MainLoop()
loop.run()
```

When a client calls the method of this endpoint I want to know the origin(sender), which just executes the function test().

I know that dbus provides this in the request eg. like
:.1.23 
but I don't found a solution to access this information with python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include a MethodCallContext in your method signature (it's a named argument so has to be `dbus_context`):

```
  def test(self, testarg, dbus_context):
    print(f'"{testarg}" received from {dbus_context.sender}')
```

I have no idea if this is considered an implementation detail of pydbus or part of the API.

Comment: Thanks, this works. Do you know where this is documented, since I was not able to find this in the documentation.

Comment: I dont think it is documented (hence the last comment in my answer): I found this in a similar situation by reading the source code

Comment: It is in this pydbus example: https://github.com/LEW21/pydbus/blob/master/examples/polkit/service.py. Searching the rest of the source code shows it’s not documented. You could [file a bug](https://github.com/LEW21/pydbus/issues/new) about getting it documented.